# Using Python and tkinter to output a line of text based on sensor input

Tags: python, tkinter, sensors

In fear of asking a silly question, and with the knowledge that I am in over my head, Im hoping that someone will lead me in the right direction.

Im working on an art project where, using a PiTop with a proximity sensor, when people get within a certain distance of the sensor, the text will change using tkinters message system (to be honest any way is doable, as long as I can set a black window with white text, and this is the only way I have found it to (almost) work). I have come to the realization that this is more complicated than I anticipated, so the basic Python skills I have (or apparently dont have) wont suffice for me to pull this off. Either way, here is the basic code I have made. I have been able to print the text (and use the array to get the word to create a sentence I want in Norwegian), but I dont understand how to actually run the measuring of distance code, and then trigger the new word as someone is approaching the sensor at a specific distance. The code as it stands now looks like this:

```
from ptpma.components import PMAUltrasonicSensor, PMALed
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *
import random

ultrasonic_sensor = PMAUltrasonicSensor("D4") #initialize the sensor

#print(ultrasonic_sensor.distance) shows the distance to the sensor
#sleep(0.1)

#random array for the various words
i = ['hensynsfull', 'nyttig','nådig','overbærende','sjenerøs','sympatisk','barmhjertig','altruistisk','anstendig','artig','behagelig','blid','dannet','dydig',
'edel','elskelig','elskverdig','ettergivende','fin','fredelig','fortrolig','fredsommelig','from','føyelig','galant','gemyttlig','god',
'godhjertet','godlynt','hengivende','hjelpsom','hjertelig','hyggelig','høflig','idealistisk','kjærlig','koselig','lun',
'lydig','lyttende','medgjørlig','mild','mottagelig','omsorgsfull','omtenksom','oppmerksom','rolig','skikkelig','spak','stillferdig',
'sømmelig','søt','tam','tillitsfull','varm','velmenende','veloppdragen','velvillig','vennlig','anstrengt','avvikende','flau','irritabel','nervøs',
'opprørt','rastløs','rådvill','selvbevisst','sårbar','urolig','usikker','uvel','angstfull','anspent','barsk','bedrøvet','bekymret',
'brå','engstelig','famlende','feig','forfjamset','forknytt','forlegen','forskrekket','forskremt','foruroliget','fryktsom','hissig','hvileløs',
'livlig','molefonken','motløs','nedstemt','oppjaget','oppspilt','pessimistisk','optimistisk','redd','sint','skremt','sjenert','skvetten',
'sky','spent','stressa','trist','ubesluttsom','usikker','utrygg','utålmodig']
tilfeldig = random.choice(i)
satt_sammen = "Hvorfor"'\n'"er du litt"'\n'+tilfeldig+"?"
#end random choice

#lage vindu i tkinter
master = Tk()

master.geometry("720x1440") #size of window
master.configure(background='black')
w = Message(master, text=satt_sammen)
w.config(anchor=CENTER, justify='center', pady=300, padx=200, bg='black', fg='white', font=('helvetica light', 60))

w.pack()
mainloop()
```

The only thing the program currently does is it updates the text with a new word from the array every time I open the window. I appreciate any input. I have searched and found some help along the way, but I dont really understand how I can have this checking for input (sensor) and consequently change the text dynamically based on that input.

---

So this is where we are currently at:

```
from ptpma.components import PMAUltrasonicSensor, PMALed
import tkinter as tk # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import random
ultrasonic_sensor = PMAUltrasonicSensor("D4") #initialize the sensor

# --- functions ---



def update_text():
    print(ultrasonic_sensor.distance) 
    if ultrasonic_sensor.distance < 40:
        w['text'] = random.choice(i)+"?"

    else:
        w['text'] = ""        

    master.after(5000, update_text) # run it again after 1000ms




def print_distance():
    print(ultrasonic_sensor.distance)
    master.after(40, print_distance)





# --- main ---



i = ['hensynsfull', 'nyttig','nådig','overbærende','sjenerøs','sympatisk','barmhjertig','altruistisk','anstendig','artig','behagelig','blid','dannet','dydig',
'edel','elskelig','elskverdig','ettergivende','fin','fredelig','fortrolig','fredsommelig','from','føyelig','galant','gemyttlig','god',
'godhjertet','godlynt','hengivende','hjelpsom','hjertelig','hyggelig','høflig','idealistisk','kjærlig','koselig','lun',
'lydig','lyttende','medgjørlig','mild','mottagelig','omsorgsfull','omtenksom','oppmerksom','rolig','skikkelig','spak','stillferdig',
'sømmelig','søt','tam','tillitsfull','varm','velmenende','veloppdragen','velvillig','vennlig','anstrengt','avvikende','flau','irritabel','nervøs',
'opprørt','rastløs','rådvill','selvbevisst','sårbar','urolig','usikker','uvel','angstfull','anspent','barsk','bedrøvet','bekymret',
'brå','engstelig','famlende','feig','forfjamset','forknytt','forlegen','forskrekket','forskremt','foruroliget','fryktsom','hissig','hvileløs',
'livlig','molefonken','motløs','nedstemt','oppjaget','oppspilt','pessimistisk','optimistisk','redd','sint','skremt','sjenert','skvetten',
'sky','spent','stressa','trist','ubesluttsom','usikker','utrygg','utålmodig']
tilfeldig = random.choice(i)
satt_sammen = "Hvorfor"'\n'"er du litt"'\n'+tilfeldig+"?"

master = tk.Tk()

master.geometry("720x1440") #size of window
master.configure(background='black')


w = tk.Message(master) # empty string,`update_text()` will set first text
x = tk.Message(master)

update_text() 
w.config(width=720, pady=50, padx=20, bg='black', fg='white', font=('helvetica light', 60))
x.config(width=720, anchor='center', justify='center', bg='black', fg='white', font=('helvetica light', 60), text="Hvorfor er du litt")

x.pack()


w.pack()

print_distance()
#create_sentence()

master.mainloop()
```

What happens now is that whenever someone steps in front of the sensor at a distance of 40, the variable changes to a specific word, and is on screen for a set amount of time. After that, if noone is in front, it goes blank.
My problem is that I would want the following, and cant get it to work:

In pseudocode: If someone is in front of the sensor at a certain distance, immediately set the word from the array. Leave the word there for as long as the person is in front, and when the sensor no longer registers a person in front (the sensor value is above 40 in this case) leave the word for one second, then go blank. Cooldown for 5 seconds, then repeat the function.

They way it is now, if someone is just standing in front of the sensor it keeps adding a new word, defeating the "purpose" of the "Why machine" I am trying to make...

If someone has any input on this it would be great.

Also - to move the two children down from the top would be awesome, but I cant seem to use the pady(x,x) value to only move it down from the top, not pad both bottom and top together.

Sorry if this is a lot to ask, but appreciate the help so far.

Comment: you can use `Button to run code which will check distance and change text. Or run this function before `mainloop()` and inside this function use `master.after(milliseconds, the_same_function)` to run the same function again after `milliseconds`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `master.after(milliseconds, function_name)` to run again function which will check sensor and change text.

I don't have sensor so I use random to change text every 1000ms (1s)

```
#from ptpma.components import PMAUltrasonicSensor, PMALed
import tkinter as tk # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import random

# --- functions ---

def update_text():
    #print(ultrasonic_sensor.distance) shows the distance to the sensor
    w['text'] = random.choice(i)
    master.after(1000, update_text) # run it again after 1000ms

# --- main ---

#ultrasonic_sensor = PMAUltrasonicSensor("D4") #initialize the sensor

i = ['hensynsfull', 'nyttig','nådig','overbærende','sjenerøs','sympatisk','barmhjertig','altruistisk','anstendig','artig','behagelig','blid','dannet','dydig',
'edel','elskelig','elskverdig','ettergivende','fin','fredelig','fortrolig','fredsommelig','from','føyelig','galant','gemyttlig','god',
'godhjertet','godlynt','hengivende','hjelpsom','hjertelig','hyggelig','høflig','idealistisk','kjærlig','koselig','lun',
'lydig','lyttende','medgjørlig','mild','mottagelig','omsorgsfull','omtenksom','oppmerksom','rolig','skikkelig','spak','stillferdig',
'sømmelig','søt','tam','tillitsfull','varm','velmenende','veloppdragen','velvillig','vennlig','anstrengt','avvikende','flau','irritabel','nervøs',
'opprørt','rastløs','rådvill','selvbevisst','sårbar','urolig','usikker','uvel','angstfull','anspent','barsk','bedrøvet','bekymret',
'brå','engstelig','famlende','feig','forfjamset','forknytt','forlegen','forskrekket','forskremt','foruroliget','fryktsom','hissig','hvileløs',
'livlig','molefonken','motløs','nedstemt','oppjaget','oppspilt','pessimistisk','optimistisk','redd','sint','skremt','sjenert','skvetten',
'sky','spent','stressa','trist','ubesluttsom','usikker','utrygg','utålmodig']

master = tk.Tk()

master.geometry("720x1440") #size of window
master.configure(background='black')

w = tk.Message(master) # empty string,`update_text()` will set first text

w.config(anchor='center', justify='center', pady=300, padx=200, bg='black', fg='white', font=('helvetica light', 60))
w.pack()

update_text()  # run it first time

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: What a life saver. I will try this out and post the code if I get it to work. I think I understand what you mean, and hopefully this will work out. Appreciate the input tremendously.